# SSRS : Wingdings check box not displayed in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: checkbox, reporting-services, unicode, wingdings

I am trying to display the checkbox on the SSRS report based on the value of a Boolean field wingdings font. My expression looks like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!ColorCheck.Value,chr(254),chr(168))
```

This works fine in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox.

I tried the Unicode alternate for this (Arial Unicode MS Font)

```
=iif(Fields!ColorCheck.Value,chr(0252),chr(0251))
```

I get the error "Procedure Call or Argument is not valid"

Is there any workaround for this. any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE : I used the Images(image of a check mark) and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a checkbox using the following example.

```
=IIF(Fields!ColorCheck.Value,chr(254),o)
```

You may refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31692730/2585788)

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert -> Indicator, more information https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2012/08/04/displaying-checkboxes-in-an-ssrs-report

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)